# SQL get data from multipe tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to return the follow question in SQL.

*In which action movie play more female then male?*

I got a table which movie_id/title/genre, a table with cast_id/gender.
And between this table a link table with movie_id and cast_id.

Can someone explain how to extract the data from a construction like this?

I came up with this so far

```
SELECT titel, geslacht, genre
FROM imdb.film
INNER JOIN imdb.cast ON cast.cast_id = film.film_id
```

Comment: When asking such a question, start by providing sample data and desired results.  This will help you think about the question, the answer, and perhaps how to achieve it.

Comment: alright I will try to do that next time. Thanks for the advice. But is it needed to down vote my post? @marc_s

Comment: @P.B: I did **not** downvote your question ....

Answer (score 0):

You can join the three tables involved and `group by` title to check for the condition.

```
SELECT f.title
FROM imdb.film f
INNER JOIN imdb.cast c ON c.cast_id=f.film_id
INNER JOIN link_table l ON l.movie_id=f.movie_id and l.cast_id=c.cast_id
WHERE f.genre = 'ACTION'
GROUP BY f.title
HAVING SUM(c.gender = 'F') > SUM(c.gender = 'M')
```

Replace link_table in the query with the actual table name.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. I got a question about : `INNER JOIN imdb.cast c ON c.cast_id=f.film_id`  This puts every cast member from their movie in a table?

And about `Having SUM` if I run it like this it says : `function sum(boolean) does not exist` @vkp